# Store user input if not equal to another field in gridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

the following code will store a score entered in txtplayer1score which is specific a column and row withing a Gridview. I need it to check that the result entered in txtplayer1score is not the same as what's already displayed in txtplayer2score which is next to it on the same row. I think I have the following code correct apart from I don't know how to declare txtplayer2score. I think I just need to set the part where I've put "????????????" below..

```
Protected Sub txtPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    '*** SAVE RESULT PLAYER 1***
    SelectWhichRound()
    Session("compID")=Request.QueryString("compID")
    Dim txtplayer1score As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim txtplayer2score As TextBox = ??????????????
  If txtplayer1score.text <> txtplayer2score.text Then
    Dim frames As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtplayer1score.text)
    Dim hdnPlayerID As HiddenField = txtplayer1score.Parent.FindControl("hdnPlayerID")
    Dim DBConnect15 As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect15.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect15.Command(db, "UpdateSaveResult")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("compID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = Guid.Parse(Session("compID"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("round", SqlDbType.Varchar,1 , ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = Session("round")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("frames", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = frames
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("accountID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,  ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = Guid.Parse(hdnPlayerID.value)
        db.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
  Else
      txtplayer1score.text=""
  End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your datagrids `cellvaluechanged` event to capture when the values have changed.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValueChanged

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim playeronescore As String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("txtplayeronescore").Value
        Dim playertwoscore As String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("txtplayerTwoScore").Value

        'REST OF YOUR CODE


    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. Need this: Dim txtplayer2score As TextBox = txtplayer1score.Parent.FindControl("txtplayer2score")